# VPN disconnects every 20 mins in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I have started using Ubuntu for my Job usage and I am experiencing VPN issue.I am connecting my VPN(pulse secure) successfully thereafter my network gets struck.Again i have to disconnect from network and i will reconnect the same.

Here is my syslog

```
Aug 17 22:21:02 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988662.7765] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Aug 17 22:21:02 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988662.7765] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.7324] device (tun0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed') [10 20 41]
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.7370] keyfile: add connection in-memory (3c0a8014-6c1f-4cd4-b4be-65a1fe1eb8a2,"tun0")
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.7386] device (tun0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed') [20 30 41]
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.7414] device (tun0): Activation: starting connection 'tun0' (3c0a8014-6c1f-4cd4-b4be-65a1fe1eb8a2)
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.7438] device (tun0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.7455] device (tun0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.7470] device (tun0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.7500] device (tun0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.7519] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.7537] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.8035] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 dbus[692]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.8045] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.8046] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 NetworkManager[24286]: <info>  [1502988663.8047] policy: set 'tun0' (tun0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 dbus[692]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: new request (1 scripts)
Aug 17 22:21:03 maa1apnb663183 nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...
Aug 17 22:21:08 maa1apnb663183 whoopsie[703]: [22:21:08] offline
Aug 17 22:21:08 maa1apnb663183 whoopsie[703]: [22:21:08] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
Aug 17 22:21:08 maa1apnb663183 whoopsie[703]: [22:21:08] Network connection may be a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
Aug 17 22:34:43 maa1apnb663183 systemd-timesyncd[682]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Aug 17 22:34:54 maa1apnb663183 systemd-timesyncd[682]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.199:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Aug 17 22:35:04 maa1apnb663183 systemd-timesyncd[682]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

I tried the following:

From the logs i understood something i have issue on routing tables.

Before connect to my VPN

```
maa1apnb663183@maa1apnb663183:/var/log$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
143.116.250.163 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   1      0        0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
```

After connected to my VPN

```
maa1apnb663183@maa1apnb663183:/var/log$ sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         148.164.24.242  0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp2s0
143.116.250.163 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   1      0        0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp2s0
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    1      0        0 wlp2s0
```

I have tried this step on internet by adding duplicate entries on(Network connections -> your VPN connection -> IPv4 settings -> Routes -> Add ...) and checked "Ignore automatically obtained routes" checkbox.
- restarted VPN connection

But no luck still my issue persist .

One important note:
When am connecting to Airtel broadband I have no issue with my VPN one week before I switched my Home network to ACT afterwards am facing this issue also I dont find any issues when tried in my mobile network by tethering.

I have seen on internet many of them facing similar kind of issue but mine i suspect due to ISP.

Any suggestions guys ?

Comment: You're using WiFi. Is it stable when not connected to the VPN? Most likely not. There's where you troubleshooting should start, not routing. If it connects the route is fine;disconnecting afterwards is not a routing issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a stable network actually . I tried both Wifi and USB connection . Yesterday I spoke to my ISP because earlier I used Airtel broadband but I don't find any issues recently I switched to ACT  afterwards am facing an issue with my VPN . If I tethering my mobile network I don't find any issues with my VPN